# How to write a custom build() function for lombok , for a set datatype which has a singular annotation?

Tags: java, java-8, annotations, lombok

```
@ToString
@EqualsAndHashCode
@Getter
@Builder(builderClassName = "Builder")
public class elements{

  @Singular("item")
  private final Set<int> items;

  private final int b;

  public static final class Builder {

    public elements build(){

      return new elements(items, b);

    }
  }


}
```

The constructor works when there is no singular annotation , but when I have a singular annotation on the set, the constructor says it is not available.

Java.util.set  cannot be Java.util.ArrayList

So, What is the correct way to call this constructor ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When using `@Singular`, the `build()` method generated by lombok becomes quite complex (and other parts of the generated builder, too). Here is what lombok generates by default (extracted from the delombok output of your example):

```
    public Elements build() {
        java.util.Set<Integer> items;
        switch (this.items == null ? 0 : this.items.size()) {
        case 0: 
            items = java.util.Collections.emptySet();
            break;

        case 1: 
            items = java.util.Collections.singleton(this.items.get(0));
            break;

        default: 
            items = new java.util.LinkedHashSet<Integer>(this.items.size() < 1073741824 ? 1 + this.items.size() + (this.items.size() - 3) / 3 : java.lang.Integer.MAX_VALUE);
            items.addAll(this.items);
            items = java.util.Collections.unmodifiableSet(items);
        }
        return new Elements(items, b);
    }
```

You can use that as a starting point for your customized `build()` method.

Comment: Looks like, When I use set and singular lombok is creating it's internal datatype using arrayList. May be I need to write a custom constructor taking in arrayList for the main class.

Comment: Of course you can stick with a simple `build()` method and write your own constructor that takes a list, but then the constructor has to perform the conversion to a set. So you'll need the fancy `@Singular` code that lombok generates anyway. Then you should put it where lombok would put it, and not add another constructor (unless you have a really good reason for it).

Comment: @BloomBlack There's a Lombok configuration allowing to use Guava, and then the whole `build` method becomes something like `return new Element(items==null ? ImmutableSet.of() : ImmutableSet.copyOf(items), b)` as Guava handles the cases internally.